# mydata.feed is undefined ionic angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic `angularjs`, I want get data `json` but I have problem withe code

```
var app = angular.module('app.news', ['ionic']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?")
  .then(function(mydata) {    
      $scope.news = mydata.feed.data;
  });
});
```

**html**

```
<ion-view title="الرئيسية" id="page2" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" class=" ">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>{{news.message}}</h1>

    </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

> Error: mydata.feed is undefined

Some help please

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mydata.data.feed.data
```

Your response is wrap inside the data as it returns promise object.

The response object has these properties:

**data – {string|Object}** – The response body transformed with the transform functions.

**status – {number}** – HTTP status code of the response.

**headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.

**config – {Object}** – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.

**statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Refer [Angularjs $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: , thanks code working without error , but no data showing in html i use this `{{message}}`

Comment: Try console.log in your controller. what `$scope.news` is having. I suspect there will be no data in `message` property.